# How to verify containing values in hash tables without loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to verify containing values in hash tables without loop in javascript?
For example:

```
var a = new Object(); // or just []
a[0] = 0
a['one'] = 1;
a['two'] = 2;
a['three'] = 3;
```

Comment: What do you mean by hash tables? What have you tried? Can you paste some code?

Comment: Javascript hasn't got "hash tables", it has objects. You can check that by using the `hasOwnProperty()` function

Comment: I talk about Dictionary in vision:key-valy

Comment: Javascript doesn't have dictionaries either. It has objects.

Comment: Yes, I understand! But I just start to think about performance! I think a lot about I going to call verify containing a value  to an object about 20 times and it's very costly!

Comment: I get a bad marks to  my question and I don't understand why!

Comment: @user1129783 It is probably because you had not given an example, and the question was not clear. Now it is

Comment: @user1129783: Because [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16883652/1) is an *awful* question.

Comment: awful question when a worry about performance - it's very interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `hasOwnProperty`

```
var hash = new Object(); // or just {}
hash['one'] = 1;
hash['two'] = 2;
hash['three'] = 3;

if (hash.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    alert('Has')
}
```

Comment: I'm going to use calling my hash table many times and I think it's very costly to use loop much, that's why I want to use function like "Contains".

Comment: so this should help you, as it is a o(1) lookup

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery

```
$(hashtablename).each(function (item) {
   //code to verify.
});
```

although internally it will prob still use a loop..

Comment: Yes, it will internally use a loop.

Comment: I'm going to use calling my hash table many times and I think it's very costly to use loop much, that's why I want to use function like "Contains".

Comment: if you want to test for just one use the previous method, I understood you wanted to check each one...either way, do not worry about performance, first write good readable code, then make changes if you need to..